# Branch and ARM program counter

Tags: arm, cortex-m

My understanding is the ARM program counter points to two instructions ahead of the currently executing instruction.

How does this work with conditional branching or even a plain branch?

If you are executing op1, have a branch at op2 and then op3, does the PC point to op3? Or does it point to the next instruction contiguous from op2?

How can you do PC relative addressing with branch instructions present? Do you need to add nops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PC register in ARM points to two instructions ahead of the current instruction *in the address space*, not in the flow of execution. So the PC points to the instruction next to op2 in the given example. Whether the subsequent instruction is branch or not is irrelevant to encoding.

Comment: Thanks, I don't understand why they did this though if it's not branch dependent.

Comment: The fact thumbv2 is variable length instructions make it even more confusing and ridiculous.